# Google Search Console error: Alternate page with proper canonical tag

Tags: google-search-console, canonical-url, search

The content of my site is completely unique, but for a few days now, Google has been showing an error for some pages of the site that have good rankings:

> Alternate page with proper canonical tag

The URLs of sites that show as canonical are also very strange, for example:

`https://www.example.com/search?q=neighborhoods%20in%20toronto&page=3`

See the following screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You can view details about this warning [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7440203?hl=en) under `Excluded`. Check the URL under `Referring page` to see if it's a duplicate, and if so, what canonical URL it has (view its source). If you have control over that page, then make sure the [canonical](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/consolidate-duplicate-urls?visit_id=637615877745959333-568654210&rd=1) tag points to the page you're trying to index (i.e., the URL that was inspected) and then click `REQUEST INDEXING`.

Comment: If you don't have control over the `Referring page`, then try to [remove it](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9689846?hl=en) and make sure you have a canonical specified in the page you're trying to index (in case it's cloned by someone else it will point back to your page).

Comment: thanks @dan .. I don't have control over the site specified by Google and when I want to remove the address from Google it sticks to this step:
Checking page URL
what's the solution?

Comment: Seems there's an issue in the Google Removal Tool, I'd try back later or ask on [their forums](https://support.google.com/websearch/community?hl=en). You didn't indicate whether this is a duplicate/cloned page - check out our questions related to [cloned](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=cloned+site) sites if that's the case.

Comment: @dan .. thank you .. The page specified by Google does not load at all and therefore may not be able to delete it at all!!